# The ending in Prometheus

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, prometheus

When Elizabeth and David take off at the end of the movie [Prometheus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_%28film%29) in the alien ship are they heading for LV-426?

Comment: Elizabeth and David Go to White Castle? There's no clear answer from this movie. All this question raises is speculation.

Comment: @wbogacz i like your answer,There is not an open ended answer to this question

Answer (score 16):

From an [interview](http://entertainment.time.com/2012/06/12/prometheus-sequel-final-scene/) with writer *Damon Lindelof*:

> **In that final scene, David wants to go to Earth, and Elizabeth wants to go to the alien home world. Where do you think they’re going?**
>
> - I think they’re going where she wants to go. His fundamental programming has been scrapped. Weyland [the man who built and programmed him] is dead and so now his programming is coming from God knows where. Is he being programmed by Elizabeth, or is it his own internal curiosity now that Weyland isn’t telling him what to do any more?
>
>   He’s always been interested in Elizabeth, remember that: He’s watching her dreams when she’s sleeping in much the same way that he watches 'Lawrence of Arabia'. He’s a strange robot that has a curious crush on a human being, and when Weyland is eliminated, I think he is genuinely interested in what she’s interested in. He reaches out partly for survival, but partly out of curiosity, and I think he’s sincere that he’ll take her wherever she wants to go.

[**LV-426**](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Acheron_%28LV-426%29) **is not the *Engineers'* homeworld.**

Comment: Thanks Oliver...that is a nice explaination of the relationship between David and Elizabeth. I do think, before it's all over with, one of the engineers has to crash one of the ships onto LV-426 to complete the whole prequel franchise of Prometheus.

Answer (score 4):

According to the new [Alien: Covenant](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/alien_covenant) trailer movie, Shaw and David went to the Engineers homeworld, the paradise planet.

Comment: Haha.  Leave it to Lindhoff to have said "I think they're going where...".  (You'll never get a straight answer out of a *Lost* producer;)